# How do you create a domain alias of a subdomain in Plesk 11?

Tags: subdomain, plesk, domain-aliasing

We currently have sites.adomain.com set up in Plesk 11 and want to use bdomain.com as an alias for sites.adomain.com. The old method does not seem to work which was:

```
vi /var/www/vhost/adomain.com/subdomains/sites/conf/vhost.conf
contents:

ServerAlias "bdomain.com"
ServerAlias "www.bdomain.com"
```

Does anyone know how to do it for the new version of Plesk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try `/var/www/vhost/sites.adomain.com/conf/vhost.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Insert your `ServerAlias` directives in a file called:

`/var/www/vhosts/system/yourdomain.com/conf/vhost.conf`

And then you have to run this for changes to take effect:

`/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/websrvmng -u --vhost-name=yourdomain.com`

Simply restart httpd won't make it work.